# How can I detect which Android native function that is hooked by Cydia Substrate: MSHookFunction?

Tags: android, hook, frida, malware-detection, cydia-substrate

I want to detect hook behavior of MSHookFunction on Android but no idea yet. This is Cydia Substrate I use in my test app *https://github.com/Breathleas/Android-Hooking-Template-Cydia-Substrate/tree/master/jni/Substrate*

After complete function hook. I tried comparing the `.text` section between the in-memory module and the shared object lib file but couldn't find the trampoline function. Here is the Frida script on the codeshare that I referenced *https://codeshare.frida.re/@lichao890427/find-android-hook/*. The origin function is hooked but `.text` section data in memory is same with shared object lib file.

Comment: For questions about reverse engineering there is a special stack exchange site https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com. when it comes to process and memory analysis you may get more attention there especially as the number of questions is way lower as here on SO.

Comment: Thank you, I will move the question to Stack exchange